# Image not showing up on Jquery Prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend

I have the following function that prepends a modal and display box with a gif loader when my user logs into Facebook.

```
function loadFacebookconnect() {
    $("#modalwait").prepend(
        "<div class='modal-backdrop id='modal-backdropid'></div>\
         <div class='modal hide fade in' id='myModal' style='display: block; '>\
             <div class='modal-body'>\
                 <p style='font-size: 28px; padding: 30px;text-align: center;'>\
                      <img style='padding-right:8px; vertical-align: text-bottom;'\
                           src='imgurl.gif'>\
                      Loading...\
                 </p>\
             </div>\
         </div>");
}
```

I call this function as I mentioned when the user authenticated with Facebook:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    loadFacebookconnect();
    window.location.reload();
});
```

My simple problem is that my image won't load when I authenticate with FB. The modal shows up and so does the text but no image. I know there's nothing wrong with the image or the CSS because when I call it regularly as shown below, it works perfectly and the image shows up.

```
<button onclick="loadFacebookconnect()">Try it</button>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and I know this problem may seem trivial but the image loader is very important as my initial graph calls do tend to take several seconds. I also looked at several SO questions [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524458/why-does-my-image-not-show-up-when-i-use-javascript-innerhtml-to-call-it), but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: That markup is incorrect, `class='modal-backdrop` is obviously missing a single-quote. I can't be sure but I think that `location.reload()` may be halting the page loading

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear. The page reload and everything works and even the modal and the loading text show up. It's just that the image will not show up when fb.event.subscribe is launched. When I click the button to loadfacebookconnect, the image shows up correctly.

Comment: src attribute of img...

check if it is the correct path.

Comment: also use " - double quotes while assigning values to HTML attributes.

Comment: The src is correct since <button onclick="loadFacebookconnect()">Try it</button> works perfectly and shows the image.

Comment: @user1011713 Try using an absolute url for image. Also check if the img tag is there and everything is fine with it using the DOM Inspector in Chrome or Firebug in FF.

Comment: Thanks @sabithpocker I'm actually using an Amazon s3 url so it is an absolute url.

Comment: And is the img tag there in DOM? Did you check with any DOM Inspector.

Comment: Why are you using window.location.reload? That is called just after the function that adds the image.

Comment: I'm reloading after fb authentication to capture and store fb data. I'm trying to actually figure out how you can check if img tag in DOM with DOM inspector.

Comment: Can you just try removing the window.reload and see if the image appears. I doubt that current page unloads when calling reload, so the request for the image might go aborted, just remove it and see if image appears(Just to check if its the problem). Also its worthy to take a look at DOM inspector for your browser.

Comment: Took out the reload and the image still wouldn't show up unfortunately.

Comment: Do you see image in the DOM (through `firebug`)? Set a breakpoint before `window.location.reload` call

Comment: From what I can tell, I don't see image in the DOM.

Comment: OK, now it just started showing the image out of the blue. I'm beyond lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#modalwait").prepend('<div class="modal-backdrop" id="modal-backdropid"></div><div class="modal hide fade in" id="myModal" style="display: block; "><div class="modal-body"><p style="font-size: 28px;padding: 30px;text-align: center;"><img style="padding-right:8px;vertical-align: text-bottom;" src="imgurl.gif"/>Loading...</p></div></div>');}
```

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately, image is still not showing up when running the FB function. The button click route shows the image though as it did before.

Comment: Your code now shows the image out of the blue. Not sure why it wouldn't work before but it's working now.

Comment: Haha! I think I have super powers. lol... Anyway, always use double quotes to assign values to the html attributes. You were using single quotes and I guess that is why the problem was there.