# return image as HTML

Tags: javascript, image, innerhtml

trying to add an image to my innerHTML.

Looked at a few prvious Q's
[Why does my image not show up when I use Javascript innerHTML to call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524458/why-does-my-image-not-show-up-when-i-use-javascript-innerhtml-to-call-it)

[Javascripts innerHTML not working for images, but works with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266104/javascripts-innerhtml-not-working-for-images-but-works-with-text)

I cant get it working, in google dev tools throws the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

with this line:

```
var newImage = document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = "<img src='images/bg-main.png></img>";
```

my code looks like:

```
   function showImage() {
    var img = document.createElement('image');
    //var newImage = document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg' border=0/></a>";
    var newImage = document.getElementById('img').innerHTML = "<img src='images/bg-main.png></img>";
    var div5 = document.createElement('div');
    div5.appendChild(newImage);

    return div5.innerHTML;

}
```

I know there are many other methods to display an image, but for the purpose of this exercise I want to return the image as an innerHTML

Comment: Why use `document.getElementById('img')`? Is the image like this: `<img id="img">`?

Comment: @ekad: img tags have no inner html anyways. they're a singleton tag. it'd have to be `<div id="img"></div>` or something. Plus, why create an image tag, and then never use it? `img.src="images/bg-main.jpg";` would do just as well. OP's got some seriously schizophrenic code there.

Comment: technically you would need outerHTML to encompass the tag too, but even then I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: Something I see that may be a problem is your src path. I *think* you would need it to be <img src='/images/bg-main.png></img>. Notice the backslash at the beginning of the path.

Comment: No mental issues thanks guys just beginning to learn JS..loads a fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.domain.com/imgSrc');
var div5 = document.createElement('div');
div5.appendChild(newImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.createElement('image')` creates a new html tag: `<image>` i suspect you're trying to add a div and apply the image as inner html. you can fix this code like the following:

```
function showImage() {
    var img = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(img)
    img.innerHTML = "<img src='images/bg-main.png></img>";
}
```